# Read from JSON where the name is

Tags: javascript

My resultjson's content:

```json
[{"name":"Dummy","id":"780828872962080819","sync_code":123456,"expiration":"2021-04-07T14:03:34.000Z"}]
```

I need the "name" from the JSON as a String, i tried with JSON.parse(resultjson).name but it didnt work.

Comment: `JSON.parse(resultjson)[0].name`?

Answer (score 1):

It's an array. You need to access an element:

```js
JSON.parse(resultjson)[0 /* or other element */].name
```